# Configure Service for Multi Tenant Dotnet Core Application

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, multi-tenant, stackexchange.redis

I am struggling with one of the issue and unable to find a solution. I am using building a multitenant dotnet core 6 application and using RedisCache, added in Program.cs as below

```
        builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(option =>
        {
            option.Configuration = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("RedisServer");
        });
```

When application run for single tenant it is working fine but for multi tenant there can be issue with duplicate key value pairs so after searching a lot I found that there is an option to set the instance like below.

```
builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(option =>
        {
            option.Configuration = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("RedisServer");
            option.InstanceName = "Tenant";
        });
```

now problem is that for all the tenants, instance name stays same. After some research I found a way to change the **options** at run time like below where I am using **IOptionsMonitor** [Options Pattern in ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0#options-interfaces)

```
public class ConfigureCacheOptions : ICacheConfigHandler
{
    private readonly ITenantHandler tenantHandler;
    private readonly IOptionsMonitor<RedisCacheOptions> redisCacheOptions;
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public ConfigureCacheOptions(ITenantHandler tenantHandler, IOptionsMonitor<RedisCacheOptions> redisCacheOptions, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.tenantHandler = tenantHandler;
        this.configuration = configuration;
        this.redisCacheOptions = redisCacheOptions;
    }

    public RedisCacheOptions GetCacheConfig()
    {
        if (tenantHandler.GetTenant() != null)
        {
            RedisCacheOptions cacheOptions = redisCacheOptions.Get(tenantHandler.GetTenant().Id);
            cacheOptions.Configuration = configuration.GetConnectionString("RedisServer");
            cacheOptions.InstanceName = tenantHandler.GetTenant().Id;
            return cacheOptions;
        }
        return redisCacheOptions.CurrentValue;
    }
}

public interface ICacheConfigHandler
{
    RedisCacheOptions GetCacheConfig();
}
```

Updated Program.cs

```
        var _tenantOption = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<ICacheConfigHandler>();
        builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(option =>
        {
            option.Configuration = _tenantOption.GetCacheConfig().Configuration;
            option.InstanceName = _tenantOption.GetCacheConfig().InstanceName;
        });
```

After all this, when application starts, it is getting the TenantId as Instance for first tenant but after this it is staying same for every other tenant and not changing. Anyone please help me out in this.

What is the best way to configure services for each tenant. I want to get values for tenantDB and configure services with those values instead of getting value for config file on startup.

**Update**
Development Environment
Dotnet Core 6

made below changes as per @King King but getting the error InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service ITenantHandler from root provider.
'

```
        builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
        {
            options.Configuration = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("RedisServer");
        });

        builder.Services.AddOptions<RedisCacheOptions>().Configure<ITenantHandler>((o, tenantHandler) =>
        {
            o.Configuration = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("RedisServer");
            o.InstanceName = tenantHandler.GetTenant().Id;
        });
```

ITenantProvider is registered as scoped and relies on ITenantRepository  and IAdminConfigProvider, and IHttpContextAccessor.

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAdminConfigProvider, AdminConfigProvider>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITenantRepository, TenantRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITenantHandler, TenantHandler>();



public class TenantHandler : ITenantHandler
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
    private readonly IAdminConfigProvider _adminConfigProvider;
    private readonly ITenantRepository _tenantRepository;

    public ITenantHandler(
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, 
        IAdminConfigProvider adminConfigProvider, 
        ITenantRepository tenantRepository)
    {
        _contextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _adminConfigProvider = adminConfigProvider;
        _tenantRepository = tenantRepository;
    }

    public Tenant GetTenant()
    {
        // Code to get Tenant
    }
}




public class CacheHandler : ICacheHandler
{
    private readonly IDistributedCache distributedCache;

    public CacheHandler(IDistributedCache distributedCache)
    {
        this.distributedCache = distributedCache;
    }

    public async Task<T> GetObjFromCacheAsync<T>(string key)
    {
        // Code to get Object from Cache
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I follow the email you sent me to reach here.
Your problem is related to the so-called `scoped options` (actually in most cases for ASP.NET Core app, the scope here is the request scope, so it's like a `per-request options`).
For `scoped options`, you may need to inject scoped services. That's already documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-di-services-to-configure-options

The extension method `AddStackExchangeRedisCache` does not support that scenario (with scoped dependencies injected) so you can try configure the options `RedisCacheOptions` explicitly. As in the link above, you can define a class implementing `IConfigureOptions` (and use an overload of the `Configure` extension method to configure it). Or using another more convenient method provided by OptionsBuilder API like this:

```
builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(option =>
{
     //here we just configure the connection string, which is the same 
     //for all requests (right?)
     option.Configuration = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("RedisServer");
});

//now for the part that's different for each request (scope)
builder.Services.AddOptions<RedisCacheOptions>()
                .Configure<ITenantHandler>((o,tenantHandler) => {
                      o.InstanceName = tenantHandler.GetTenant().Id;
                 });
```

Please note that I've not done any demo to test the code above, it's just based on what I've read (from the documentation) as well as my knowledge. It should work, but not 100% sure.

The `IOptionsMonitor` is not what you want here. It helps get the latest options when the source is changed but for your case, the source data is right from each request and you can just configure everything from that input data (at the very beginning of each request). It's all supported by the framework (so you don't have to design your own way of hooking up everything, just use the `Configuration` & `Options` API provided by the framework, as shown in the code I posted above).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I tried your solution but got this error. "Cannot resolve scoped service 'ITenantHandler' from root provider.

Comment: @FaisalSaleem that error is very weird, that means the `IConfigureOptions` behind the scenes is registered as a singleton but that's strange, from the source code I can see that it's registered as a transient.
Actually I've tried a simple console app demo to try reproducing your error but could not.
Please let me know more about your dev environment (framework version, ...), also it's better if you could post your actual code in an update section in your question.

Comment: @FaisalSaleem Now I don't have a clue on why it has such an error, in the mean time, you may want to try implementing `IConfigureOptions` explicitly but with a bit tricky part as blogged here https://andrewlock.net/the-dangers-and-gotchas-of-using-scoped-services-when-configuring-options-in-asp-net-core/#3-creating-a-new-scope-in-iconfigureoptions

I hope you can provide some more info so that I can take a deeper look into this. For my part, I'll inform you with anything new I have (at least firstly I need to be able to reproduce this error).

Comment: Added more details in update section. hopefully that will provide you more details.

Comment: @FaisalSaleem I'm not so sure what could be wrong here, the only thing which may make the difference from your side is the use of .NET 6 (which I currently don't use in my environment because I've not upgraded to VS 2022 yet). However I don't think .NET 6 may make such a weird difference.
Scoped options is a normal thing (and we need it in many scenarios), you can refer to the blog link I commented before.
I doubt that you use the `ITenantHandler` somewhere else that causes the error?
If possible, please narrow it down such as in a simple demo to see if the error still occurs

Comment: @FaisalSaleem now I can just suggest something for you to try, also reading the related stuff is what you should do. Sorry that I'm fairly busy to make a demo now but I will try sooner or later. Hope that you or I will find out something interesting here.